# celery- modify task scheduler time

Tags: python, celery

I have a period task which schedule is got from database
Because we want the value can be changed by user

```
app.conf.CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'do_something': {
        'task': 'celery_task.tasks.do_something',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=get_setting()),
        'options': { 'queue': 'do_something',
                     'expires':get_setting()}
    },
```

When I execute  `celery beat -A project --loglevel=INFO`
it run the task by every `timedelta(seconds=get_setting()`

But when I change the time in database
The task still use old schedule time
How can I let it use new schedule time????
Could it possible without restart celery beat??

Answer (score 0):

Celery offers the option to build a custom scheduler. You can read about it [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/periodic-tasks.html). Also, you can see examples in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550164/how-to-programmatically-generate-celerybeat-entries-with-celery-and-django) SE question and [this](https://github.com/zmap/celerybeat-mongo) github repository.

Shortly, you need to implement a new scheduler that syncs entries from a DB. Good luck!